# Bring any PyTorch cuda tensor in the range [0,1]

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, pytorch

Suppose I have a PyTorch Cuda Float tensor `x` of the shape `[b,c,h,w]` taking on any arbitrary value allowed by Float Tensor range. I want to normalise it in the range [0,1].

I think of the following algorithm (***but any other will also do***).

Step1: Find minimum in each batch. Call it `min` and having shape `[b,1,1,1]`.

Step2: Similarly find the maximum and call it `max`.

Step3: Use `y = (x-min)/max`. Alternatively use `y = (x-min)/(max-min)`. I don't know which one will be better. `y` should have the same shape as that of `x`.

I am using PyTorch 1.3.1.

Specifically I am unable to get the desired `min` using `torch.min()`. Same goes for `max`.

I am going to use it for feeding it to pre-trained VGG for calculating perceptual loss (after the above normalisation i will additionally bring them to ImageNet mean and std). Due to some reason I cannot enforce [0,1] range during data loading part because the previous works in my area have a very specific normalisation algorithm which has to be used but some times does not ensures [0,1] bound but will be somewhere in its vicinity. That is why at the time computing perceptual loss I have to do this explicit normalisation as a precaution. All out of the box implementation of perceptual loss I am aware assume data is in [0,1] or [-1,1] range and so do not do this transformation.

Thankyou very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most elegant way, but you can do that using `keepdim=True` and specifying each of the dimensions:

```py
channel_min = x.min(dim=1, keepdim=True)[0].min(dim=2,keepdim=True)[0].min(dim=3, keepdim=True)[0]
channel_max = x.max(dim=1, keepdim=True)[0].max(dim=2,keepdim=True)[0].max(dim=3, keepdim=True)[0]
```

Comment: Thankyou for this. I tried them in python, `channel_min` and `channel_max` work the way they should. But I found that `y = (x-min)/max` is faulty and reaps incorrect result and `y = (x-min)/(max-min)` is the only alternative. Anyways thankyou